# Turning a list of list to list of string using syntax->string

Tags: scheme, racket

Basically, I want `'( (whatever1) (whatever2) (whatever3) ... )` ===> `( "(whatever1)" "(whatever2)" "(whatever3)" )`, which is just add quotes outside of the list, and keep the contents in the list unchanged. e.g.

```
'((define X ::int)
 (define b0 :: bool (=> T (and (= X X) (= 0 0)))))
```

will be turned into:

```
'("(define X ::int)"
 "(define b0 :: bool (=> T (and (= X X) (= 0 0))))")
```

However, the following code I am using eliminate all spaces!

```
#lang racket
(require syntax/to-string)
(define lst-sub '((define x :: int) (=> T (and (= X X) (= 0 0)))))
(pretty-write (map (λ (x) (string-append "(" (syntax->string (datum->syntax #f x)) ")")) lst-sub))
```

which returns

```
("(definex::int)" "(=>T(and(=XX)(=00)))")
```

So the question is: there is no spaces anymore! 
How can I get around this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#lang racket
(define lst-sub '((define x :: int) (=> T (and (= X X) (= 0 0)))))
(pretty-write (map (λ (x) (format "~s" x)) lst-sub))
```

Comment: Oh my god! 2 lines! Totally missed the FORMAT (haven't used it a lot in Racket :(...What a lesson! In both ways :)

Answer (score 1):

Alright. I don't take the "easy" route I thought. and worked out as follows, which ends up with more lines of code :(

```
(define (toString-with-space data)
  (match data
    [(? symbol?) (string-append (symbol->string data) " ")]
    [(? number?) (string-append (number->string data) " ")]))


(define (flat-def def-lst)
  (if  (empty? def-lst)
      (list)
      (begin
        (let ([f (car def-lst)])
          (if (not (list? f))
              (cons (toString-with-space f) (flat-def (drop def-lst 1)))
              (append (list "(") (flat-def f) (flat-def (drop def-lst 1)) (list ")"))))))) 

(define (lstStr->lstChars lst-str)
  (for/fold ([l empty])
     ([el (in-list lst-str)])
     (append  l (string->list el))))


(define flat (flat-def ' (define b1 :: bool (=> (and (= X x) (= Y y)) (and (= Y y) (= X x))))))
(set! flat (append  (list "\"" "(") flat (list  ")" "\""))) 
(set! flat (lstStr->lstChars flat))
(set! flat (list->string flat))
(display flat)
```